# Retrieving mobile number for a Contact

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I'm using the [createContacts](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/contacts/createContacts.html) REST API method to create a new Contact and I'm including the MobileConnect Demographics Attribute Set in the same request, which adds the Contact in MobileConnect. We can also use the [updateContacts](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/contacts/updateContacts.html) method to update a Contact. This works fine — refer to screenshot below from the All Contacts page in Contact Builder.

However I can't find a way to **retrieve** a mobile number for an existing Contact using the SOAP or REST API. Does anyone know how to do this?

[image: All Contacts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out that you can do this using the [attributes/search](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/contacts/fetchAttributes.html) route in th REST API.

Using this method, you can retrieve **any** Attribute from any Attribute Set in your Contact Model. Very handy.

In the example below, I'm retrieving the Email Address from all Subscribers and the Mobile Number from the MobileConnect list. Note that `Contacts` is the Data Extension name used in my Population and `Contact Key` is the field value in that Data Extension (linked to the Contact Record).

You also can include other `key` name/value pairs in the attributes array to retrieve field values from other Data Extensions used in your Contact Model.

```json
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/attributes/search
Authorization: Bearer {{accessToken}}
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "request": {
        "attributes": [{
                "key": "Email Addresses.Email Address"
            },
            {
                "key": "MobileConnect Demographics.Mobile Number"
            }]

    },
    "conditionSet": {
        "operator": "And",
        "conditionSets": [],
        "conditions": [{
            "attribute": {
                "key": "Contacts.Contact Key"
            },
            "operator": "Equals",
            "value": {
                "items": ["643268b7-0d37-9aff-3685-1eb068d21b5e"]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to retrieve the mobile number for all contacts using REST API, or for a given contact using AMPScript or Server Side Javascript.

For all contacts, you can use:

```
GET: https://www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/attributeSets/name:MobileConnect%20Demographics?$page=<pageNo>
```

To retrieve a single contact mobile i use this (being **contactID** the one of the contact you want the mobile):

```
var mobileConnectDE = DataExtension.Init("DATA_EXTENSION_EXTERNAL_KEY");
var rowMobileConnect = {};
try {        
  rowMobileConnect = mobileConnectDE.Rows.Lookup(['_ContactID'], [***contactID***]);      
  Write("Retrieve status: " + Stringify(rowMobileConnect));

  for(var i in rowMobileConnect){      
     Write("MobileNumber: " + rowMobileConnect[i]['_MobileNumber']);
  }   
} catch (ex) { 
  Write("An error has occurred retrieving rows: " + Stringify(ex));  
  return; 
}
```

You can put this piece of code in a landing page.

Comment: Let me know if it works for you

Comment: The endpoint you provided will return all mobile contacts and does not appear to let you filter for individual contacts using URL parameters. However, I've found a solution, which I will post as a separate answer.